# reactive-banana webkit DOM boilerplate

Tags: reactive-banana

Is there (or does it make sense for it to be) a `reactive-banana` over `webkitgtk3`'s `DOM`? Originally I was looking for `reactive-banana-gtk` but then realized the widgets were to rigid and I saw no easy way to define new widgets from Haskell. `DOM` together with `css` on the other hand could satisfy my needs. Hope this justifies the use case.

What would I need to do to get `reactive-banana` working over `Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.DOM`?

I haven't found anything on `hackage`, `github`, nor by googling it.

Answer (score 0):

My library [Threepenny-GUI](https://wiki.haskell.org/Threepenny-gui) is a GUI library that uses the web browser as a display, so you can use HTML+JavaScript from Haskell. This may be what you are looking for.

It has FRP built-in as well. (It doesn't depend on `reactive-banana` just yet, but I expect to change this in a future release.)

Comment: I already took a look at that project, but from how I understand it, it produces a server to which you then connect a browser as your client. I don't want that. But I also realized I can use webkit to render my app but still need `reactive-banana` for `gtk`.